# How to check current password  in Rails (Devise gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jquery-validate, actioncontroller

I'm failing to check current password using jQuery validation. I'm using Devise gem and jQuery validation. Firebug says:

the problem is in my controller :

```
def checkpass
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
 respond_to do |format|
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
    format.json { render :json => @user }
 end
```

end

**with this code Firebug gives me error**

```
 406 Not Acceptable

end
```

**example of checkemail uniqueness action:**

```
 def checkemail
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
   respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :json => !@user }
  end
end
```

My js:

```
$("#edit_password").validate({
   "user[current_password]":{
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            remote: {
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkpass"
          }
 ...
 })
```

and HTML:

```
   <input type="password" size="30" name="user[current_password]" id="user_current_password" class="valid">
```

Can someone suggest how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the controller in function check_pass

```
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
  respond_to do |format|
     if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        format.json { render :json => @user }
     end
  end
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
        format.json { render :json => @user }`

Comment: if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
       format.json { render :json => @user }
    end

Comment: `Template is missing`, without respond_to do. I can't get why, when I checke uniqueness it didn't want template.

Comment: Check example in my question.

Answer (score 9):

I am using rails version 4 and when I tried doing user.authenticate I got error saying unknown methods, so I found the other method for checking if password is valid,

`valid_password?(current_password)`

I thought to share it so it might help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Password is not stored in plain text format it's a salted hash,so user can't find using password.

You can authenticate password is valid or not 
so salted hash work like

- crypted string = plaintext(password)+hashing algo(encrypt)
- some random string(salt) +crypted string then checked for match
  You can use `warden.authenticate` or `authenticate` (check docs) method on user to verify password

Comment: what you want exactly in devise you have to customize device you can use like `resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "home#index")` # Override

Comment: I think I'm close to the answer. Can you look at comments above ?

Comment: Your request is ajax?and what is the  dataType in ajax request

Comment: try to set `dataType`,or `header('Content-type: application/json');` in remote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178012/jquery-remote-validation,

Comment: dataType is already set - from Firebug : `Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8`