# Unique name check using Jquery validator Add method

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, jquery-validate

I have this form field called Template name and i have to check its uniqueness using validator addMethod function in my cakephp driven application.I can not understand how this works and how it will be validated if name is not unique.It is stoping form submission if name is unique.Below is my code.Please Help me with this and try to rectify my errors.

**Client side Code**

```
function validatefrm() {            
            var validate_frm = $("#EmailTemplateEditForm").validate({
                onkeyup: false,
            rules: {
                "data[EmailTemplate][template_name]": {
                    required:true,
                    validateTemplatename:true                        
                },
           },
           messages: {
                "data[EmailTemplate][template_name]": {
                    required:"<br/>Please Enter Template name !", 

                },
              }
            });
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateTemplatename",function (value,elememt){
        var inputElem = $('#EmailTemplateEditForm :input[name="data[EmailTemplate][template_name]"]'),
        data = { "template_name" : inputElem.val() },
        eReport = '';           
        $.ajax(
            {
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo HTTP_ROOT.'email_templates/check_unique/'?>",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {                               
            if (data !== 'true'){
                return false;
            }
            else{                   
                return true;
            }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('ajax loading error... ... ');
        return false;
    }
}); 
}, '');
```

**Server Side Coding in Controller**

```
    function check_unique(){                
         if (isset($this->params['form']['template_name'])  && !empty($this->params['form']['template_name'])){
            $template_name = trim($this->params['form']['template_name']);           
            $totaltemplates = $this->EmailTemplate->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('EmailTemplate.template_name' => $template_name)));            
            if($totaltemplates == 0)    {               
            echo(json_encode(true));  //Name is Unique
            exit;
            }
            else{
            echo(json_encode(false)); //Name already exists         

            exit;
            }
        }
            else{
            echo "false"; //invalid post var
        }

       }
    }
```

Comment: You would not create a whole new method for this.  You would simply use [the `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).

Comment: Try changing the echo in the server side code to return. Return the value to the calling ajax method instead of echoing it

Comment: @mcgowan.b, `echo` is absolutely correct for this application.

Comment: Heard of remote method,but dont know how that works.Please help me if you can @Sparky

Comment: I've always used `return` in my ajax queries and it never gives a problem. Why use `echo` over `return`?

Comment: @mcgowan.b, in this case, his server-side code is correct as specified for using this plugin and its `remote` method.

Comment: i checked the response on the client side and it is coming fine but dont know why the form isnt submitting if it is unique

Comment: @RudrakshPanigrahi, follow the links I gave you.  Linked to `remote` documentation in my first comment and linked to [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577120/jquery-validate-remote-method-usage) at top of your posting.

Comment: Also click here to see hundred of other questions tagged with jQuery Validate (keyword "remote") with code:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+remote

Comment: @mcgowan.b, as per PHP documentation, `return` _"returns program control to the calling {PHP} module"_; which has nothing to do with Ajax or JavaScript.  However, the PHP documentation states that `echo` will _"output one or more strings"_; which is exactly what we're doing... we are "outputting" a string that Ajax can pick up.