# jQuery remote validation clear error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am doing remote validation in jQuery and its working fine by showing error whenever appropriate. However, I am not use how to clear the error when the validation succeeds the second time round. The error message would have been displayed and how to clear the error second time?

FYI, I am setting the error in my function. Below is jQuery the code. I have highlighted the section asking "TODO: How to clear the error here? in the code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    validator = $("#registerForm").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                //remote:'http://agent.laserchat.app/auth/checkemail'
                remote: {
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '//agent.laserchat.app/auth/checkemail',
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $('#email').val();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'myCallback',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("myCallback data is :" + data);
                        if (data === "true")
                            validator.showErrors({
                                "email": "This email is already used"
                            });
                        else
                             // TODO: How to clear the Error here?
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            }


        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin is not the jQuery Validation Engine.  Two different plugins.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for you to craft an error message hander within `remote`.  Either put the custom message within the server-side script or within the `messages` option. That way, the plugin can properly toggle the error message automatically as designed.  If it's a single error message, just use the `messages` option.  If you need to dynamically construct a custom message based on the remote request, the message is crafted within your server-side script as a JSON response.  Any JSON string coming back is treated as failed validation and the string becomes the error message.

Comment: Sparky, its not duplicate as the question does not have an acceptable answer. Which question are you referring to by the way?

Comment: Should I remove success function?

Comment: Yes, follow [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) and the [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577120/jquery-validate-remote-method-usage).  [There are also many other usage examples here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+remote+isaccepted%3Ayes).  If the `echo` response from the server is `false`, then it fails validation.  If the `echo` response is a JSON formatted string, then it also fails validation, and the string automatically becomes the error message.  If the `echo` response is `true`, it passes validation.