# jQuery Validator addMethod only working after second call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate an input using jquery validator 'addMethod'. The main goal is to check if the current user id exists in the system and if it does a error message is displayed. To check if the user exists I make a ajax call to my controller and it returns true or false.

```
$("input[name='VATNumber']").blur(function () {

        var tbody = $(this).showLoading();

        var vatnumber = $(this).val();

        var svcUrl = "@Url.Action("CheckUserExistance", "User")";

        $.ajax({
            url: svcUrl + "?vatNumber=" + vatnumber,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                tbody.hideLoading();
                $.jGrowl("ERROR checking user.", { life: 5000, group: "error" });
            },
            success: function (result) {
                tbody.hideLoading();
                displayErrorMessage(result.data);

                //console.log(result);
                //if (result.data == false) { displayErrorMessage(); }
            }
        });

        function displayErrorMessage(result) {
            console.log(result);
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkUser", function (value) {
                return result == false;
            }, "User already exists.");

            jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkUser = { checkUser: true };

            $("input[name='VATNumber']").validate();
        }

    });
```

The problem is that the validator is not displaying the message at the right time, even so the 'result' variable is right.

Can someone help, please?

**UPDATE**

I've tried with this code and it still doesn't work. The request is not considered.

```
var vatnumber = $("input[name = 'VATNumber']").val(),
        officeid = parseInt($("input[name='OfficeID']").val(), 10);
var svcUrl = "@Url.Action("CheckUserExistance", "User")";

    $('#mainForm').validate({
        rules: {
            VATNumber: {
                required: true,
                VATNumber: true,
                remote: {
                    url: svcUrl,
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        vatNumber: vatnumber,
                        officeId: officeid
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            VATNumber:  {
                remote: "User already exists."
            }
        }
    });
```

---

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and Bootstrap

**HTML**

```
    <div class="par control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="VATNumber">NIF</label>
                    <div class="controls">

<input class="input-large" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="MaxLengthAttribute" data-val-maxlength-max="50" id="VATNumber" name="VATNumber" type="text" value="2345678">
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="VATNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$("input[name='VATNumber']").addClass("checkUser");

    var vatnumber = $("input[name = 'VATNumber']").val(),
        officeid = parseInt($("input[name='OfficeID']").val(), 10);

    var svcUrl = "@Url.Action("CheckUserExistance", "User")";

    console.log(svcUrl + " " + vatnumber);

    $('#mainForm').validate({
        rules: {
            VATNumber: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: svcUrl,
                    type: "post",
                    // for troubleshooting
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('status: ' + textStatus); // status
                        console.log('error: ' + errorThrown); // error
                    },
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        // fires after the request, even if there is an error
                        console.log('ajax is finished: ' + textStatus);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            VATNumber: {
                remote: "User already exists."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Regarding your edit:  you declared a rule called `VATNumber: true`.  There is no such rule called `VATNumber`, so this is the point where it fails, before it even reaches the `remote` method.  Also, not a big deal, but `vatNumber: vatnumber` is not needed inside `data` option.  The value of the field itself is already sent by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code...

```
$("input[name='VATNumber']").blur(function () {

    ....

    $.ajax({
        ....
    });

    function displayErrorMessage(result) {

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkUser", function (value) {
            return result == false;
        }, "User already exists.");

        jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkUser = { checkUser: true };

        $("input[name='VATNumber']").validate();
    }

});
```

**Problems:**

1. Everything is inside a `blur` handler.  I'm not sure why you need this when the jQuery Validate plugin already uses a `focusout` handler by default.  You can eliminate the `blur()` handler entirely.
2. You've attached the `.validate()` method to an `input`.  You cannot do this.  The `.validate()` method only gets attached to the `<form>` element.
3. You've put the `.validate()` method inside of a `displayErrorMessage` function which is nested inside your `blur` handler function.  However, the `.validate()` method is used for ***initializing*** the plugin on your form and should be called **once** and only on DOM ready.
4. You've also put `.addMethod()` inside of a `displayErrorMessage` function which is nested inside your `blur` handler function.  However, the `.addMethod()` method is used for ***creating/initializing*** the new rule and should be called **once** and only on DOM ready.  In this case, your new rule/method does not appear to be used anywhere, not needed, and not even properly constructed.
5. Your `.ajax()` is completely independent of the jQuery Validate plugin.  However, the plugin already contains an `ajax` method called `remote`, where its sole function is to remotely check with the server; to check if a username already exists, for example.

> "The main goal is to check if the current user id exists in the system and if it does a error message is displayed."

Then you don't even need the `.ajax()` or the `.addMethod()` method at all. Simply properly implement [the `remote` rule/method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            VATNumber: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    // your other options
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Your server-side code can return a `true` or `false` indicating pass or fail validation.  Alternatively, if you return a JSON encoded string, then it fails validation and the JSON string automatically becomes the validation message.

Also see:  [jQuery Validate remote method usage to check if username already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577120/jquery-validate-remote-method-usage)

---

**EDIT**:

Based on edited OP and his comments...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // <-- everything inside a DOM ready handler?

    $('#mainForm').validate({  // <-- 'mainForm' is ID of your <form></form>?
        rules: {
            VATNumber: {
                required: true,
                // VATNumber: true, // <-- NO SUCH METHOD/RULE
                remote: {
                    url: svcUrl, // <-- positively verify the URL
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        vatNumber: vatnumber,  // <-- redundant
                        officeId: officeid
                    },
                    // for troubleshooting
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('status: ' + textStatus); // status
                        console.log('error: ' + errorThrown); // error
                    },
                    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        // fires after the request, even if there is an error
                        console.log('ajax is finished: ' + textStatus);
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ....
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sparky ! After some research I found the remote function. I'm considering all the problems you've listed and I'll give you some feedback right after I solve this.

Comment: I'm having trouble calling my action method.

Comment: @xatz, you declared a non-existant rule called `VATNumber` inside `VATNumber`.  This stops validation before it reaches the `remote` method.  You should be getting a console error about an "undefined method" because of this.

Comment: I don't get any error which is weird and I've tried without that rule and still doesn't work :(

Comment: @xatz, I know that if you put a non-existent rule into the list, it stops cold at at that point.  Carefully check your syntax and look at my edits.   Use your console for troubleshooting... it will also give you useful information about the server response codes from the `remote` method's `ajax` request.   Inspect your DOM to verify that the URL for your `remote` method is correct.

Comment: I tested everything and still can't get an error at the console and the method doesn't get hit.

Comment: @xatz, are you sure the URL is being constructed correctly?  Inspect your DOM and verify this.  Thousands of websites, including my own, are using the `remote` method without any problems.  I'm not sure what else I can tell you.  You can also try putting some `console.log` lines into the options to see what you get.  See my edits.

Comment: unfortunately nothing is being written at the console. The URL is constructed correctly and the DOM exists. The rule is just not being considered. :(

Comment: @xatz, for the code you've shown, that does not make any sense at all.  Does the `required` rule work?

Comment: @xatz, you should have mentioned that minor detail!  If the `required` rule isn't working either, then something is breaking the entire plugin.  Is your `.validate()` method wrapped in a DOM ready handler?  Is your `.validate()` method properly attached to your `form`?  You did not show us any HTML whatsoever, so it's impossible for me to know.

Comment: Sorry @Sparky but as it worked with the first code I thought it was supposed to work correctly. I'll edit my original post.

Comment: @xatz, JavaScript does not care about your framework, so only show the ***rendered*** HTML as seen by the browser.  Also, if you're using ASP, then make sure you're NOT using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin as this calls its own instance of `.validate()` thus totally negating yours.

Comment: @xatz, I can't see any `form` tags so I just have to assume they're correct?  However, your `input` for `VATNumber` already has a `value` so of course the `required` rule is never going to fire.  Just make sure you don't have `unobtrusive-validation` installed.  Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort helping me @Sparky. I turned false the UnobtrusiveJavaScript key at Web.config to try if the remote method was called and didn't get any luck. Running out of ideas as well :(

Answer (score 2):

Despite all the help from @Sparky (thank you so much) and after running out of ideas, I talked to a friend and he said to try calling the ajax inside the `addMethod`. And it worked better than the first attempt. So here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[name='VATNumber']").addClass("checkUser");

    var vatnumber = $("input[name = 'VATNumber']").val(),
        officeid = parseInt($("input[name='OfficeID']").val(), 10);

    var svcUrl = "@Url.Action("CheckUserExistance", "User")";

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkUser", function (value, element) {
        var exists = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: svcUrl + "?vatNumber=" + value
                        + "&officeId=" + officeid,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, err) {
                $.jGrowl("ERROR checking user.", { life: 5000, group: "error" });
            },
            success: function (result) {
                exists = result;
            }
        });
        return exists;
    }, "User already exists.");
    //});

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkUser = { required: true, checkUser: true };
});
```