# jQuery validator remote method

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the remote validation method and have questions about the following section of http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/.

*The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.*

If the server `echo('custom error');`, it does not pass validation, but the error is not displayed.  Why not?

If the server executes `echo(null);` or `echo(false);`, or doesn't have an echo at all, the client doesn't appear to get a response, it doesn't pass validation, and the default message isn't displayed.  Shouldn't it display the default message?  Similarly, if the server executes `echo('undefined');`, the client receives 'undefined' but the default message isn't displayed.

Server Script

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/plain;');

  //The following passes validation
  //echo('true');

  //The following results in the client receiving 1, and "1" is displayed as error
  //echo(true);
  //echo(1);
  //echo('1');

  //The following will trigger the default message
  //echo(0);
  //echo('null');
  //echo('false');
  //echo('0');

  //The following results in no ajax response to client, and no message is displayed.
  //Doesn't this result in client getting undefined which should display the default message
  //echo(null);
  //echo(false);
  //no echo at all

  //Client receives "undefined", but it doesn't display the default message.  Shouldn't it?
  //echo('undefined');

  //Client receives "custom error", but it doesn't display this text.  Shouldn't it?
  echo('custom error');
?>
```

Client Script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                var validator=$("#myForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        bla: {
                            minlength:2,
                            maxlength:4,
                            required:true,
                            remote: {url:"validate.php",type:'get',data:{a:1,b:2,c:3}}
                            //remote: "validate.php"
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        bla: {
                            remote:"default message"
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="post">
            <input name="bla" id="bla" value="">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Since there are already so many questions regarding confusion with using the `remote` method, I *almost* closed this as a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16577120/594235).  However, yours is a little more specific and *maybe* can be used in the future to close others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "If the server echo('custom error');, it does not pass validation, but the error is not displayed. Why not?"

Because you need to send the server response back as a JSON string; not a regular string and not a boolean.

```
echo json_encode('this is going to be the error message');
```

This is going to pass validation...

```
echo json_encode('true');
```

This is going to fail validation and use the *default* message...

```
echo json_encode('false');
```

These will also work as above...

```
echo 'true'  // pass
echo 'false' // fail using default message
```

This will NOT work...

```
echo 'custom message';
```

---

> //The following results in the client receiving 1, and "1" is displayed as error [snip] ....

Docs:

> *"The response is evaluated as JSON and must be... any false, undefined or null for invalid elements"*

Anything not being interpreted as a string containing `"true"`, will FAIL validation.  **Since you're not echoing these responses as JSON, your various error messages are proven to be very unpredictable.**

Yes, I agree the documentation is a bit ambiguous about the JSON wording.  *"evaluated as JSON"* seems to imply that the plugin is doing the conversion.  This is not the case.  The server response **must** already be JSON when it's evaluated.

---

```
type:'get'
```

`GET` is already the default for the `remote` method and does not need to be specified.

---

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/jzaefferer/validation-content/pull/12) to get the documentation changed into this:

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be `"true"` for valid elements, and can be `"false"`, `undefined`, or `null` for invalid elements, using the default error message. If the serverside response is a string, eg. `"That name is already taken, try peter123 instead"`, this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default.

Comment: That was driving me crazy!  Thank you

Comment: @user1032531, I think many people have problems simply because of the wording from the documentation.  I've proposed a change to the docs as described in my edit above.  Feel free to comment about this on [the GitHub thread](https://github.com/jzaefferer/validation-content/pull/12).  Thanks.