# Jquery validation on modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with validating a field on a modal form.
I created a cusom validation method called "Exists" and i use some more standard rules. It look like to me that "Validate" method does nothing because my form is valid in all cases...
My "Validate" method is in part of code when modal is visible, so I don't know what is a problem.

```
Here is my code:

JavaScript:
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $.validator.addMethod("Exists", function (value) {

            var isSuccess = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ControlerName/Method?JIB=" + $('#JIB').val(),
                data: {},
                async: false,
                success:
                    function (msg) { isSuccess = msg === "0" ? false : true }
            });

            return isSuccess

        }, "Wrong JIB");

   


  $('#btn-open-modal').on('click', function (e) {
            $("#dialog-1").modal('show');
           
        });
     
   
        $("#btn-ok").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault;

           var validator = $("#frm").validate({
                JIB: {
                    "required": true,
                    "minlength": 13,
                    "maxlength": 13,
                    "digits": true,
                    "Exists": true
                },

                onkeyup: false,
                onclick: false,
                onfocusout: false
            });

           if (!($("#frm-dodaj-na-zahtjev").valid())) {
                validator.focusInvalid();
                console.log("0");
            }
            else {
               console.log("1");
            }
          
        });

 });
</script>
```

```html
Modal:

 <button type="button" class="btn ink-reaction btn-raised btn-primary" id="#btn-open-modal">Open</button>

<div id="dialog-1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Enter ID</h3>
            </div>

             <form id="frm" class="form form-validation floating-label" role="form" action="#" method="post">

            <div class="modal-body ">
                <br/>
               
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 ">
                        <input type="text" id="JIB" class="form-control input-lg" name="JIB"  />
                        <label for="JIB">JIB</label>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  
                <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="btn-cancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">CANCEL</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btn-ok" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            </div>
                 </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here...

```
 $("#btn-ok").on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault;
     var validator = $("#frm").validate({
         jibdodaj: {
             "required": true,
              "minlength": 13,
              "maxlength": 13,
              "digits": true,
              "Exists": true
         },
         onkeyup: false,
         onclick: false,
         onfocusout: false
         ....
```

1. The `.validate()` method does not belong inside a `click` handler for the form.  The `.validate()` method is used for ***initializing*** the plugin on your form and only gets called once after the form is created, typically within a DOM ready handler.  Once initialized, it **automatically** captures the `click` event of the submit button.
2. You have the `jibdodaj` object improperly placed.  It belongs ***inside*** of the `rules` object, which you've failed to include.
3. The `name` of your field is `JIB`, so what is `jibdodaj` supposed to be?  Inside the `rules` object, the fields can only be referenced by `name`.
4. Your custom `Exists` method could be replaced with [the built-in `remote` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/).  Why reinvent the wheel.  From your server, if using PHP, `echo` a `"true"` or `"false"` to indicate "pass" or "fail" validation.  See ["jQuery Validate remote method usage to check if username already exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16577120/594235) for more information.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var validator = $("#frm").validate({
         rules: {
             JIB: { // <- this is the NAME of the field
                 "required": true,
                  "minlength": 13,
                  "maxlength": 13,
                  "digits": true,
                  //"Exists": true // <- should replace with `remote`
                  remote: {
                      url: "/ControlerName/Method",
                      async: false,
                      type: "post" // default is GET
                  }
             }
         },
         messages: {
             JIB: {
                 remote: "Wrong JIB"
             }
         },
         onkeyup: false,
         onclick: false,
         onfocusout: false
         ....
```