# Checking for unique username with jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

this is related to jquery-validate

I am trying to improve jquery validate on my site, by adding an option that I call "unique" that checks if a chosen username is already used by another user or not.
To do so I check in AJAX on my DB if the username is unique or not (this works), however this.optional( element ) does not work... I think it is because "this" is not referring to "unique" anymore when on the function but I can't see a way around it.... I spent 3 hours on it looking on the web for the answer but can't find what's going on...

```
unique: function( value, element )
{
   $.post('includes/userunique.php',{uname:value},
   function(response,status)
   {
      return this.optional( element ) || response > 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  IMO @Barmar, the OP should be using `remote` to check if a name is taken, and that would be a duplicate of this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16577120/594235

Comment: @Sparky Didn't read carefully, so I didnt notice that this was related to jquery-validate, just saw the async problem.

Comment: @Sparky I've reopened, you can now close with that dupe.

Comment: @barmar - no problem and done.

Comment: To the OP: the `this` from `this.optional(element)` changes its meaning when you put inside the `$.post()` function.  If you insist on this approach, save your ajax response in a variable and do your `return` from ***outside*** of the `$.post()`.  Otherwise, simply implement the `remote` function as per the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Method `post` is async, you won't be able to get the result from ajax call like that. Async means that code execution is not waiting for the ajax call to finish.

Method `post` returns a promise with callbacks methods for `done`, `fail` and `always` where you can evaluate result or react to an error.

For more information check [`post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) official documentation

Comment: Thanks, I understand, however, is there any way to change it a bit and integrate the change of the element directly within the function like: unique: function( value, element )
{
free = $.post('includes/userunique.php',{uname: value},function(response,status){return this.optional( element ) ||  response > 0;});
} This doesn't work unfortunately as I think "this" is not defined when on the function but I am sure there is something to do?

Comment: @Iron: I'm leaving now but I'll try to take a look later, please add your comment as edit in the question as it's hard to read without format.

Comment: thanks a lot mate! will do

Answer (score -1):

The syntax you'll need to use as noted by Claudio would be.

```
unique: function(value, element) {
    $.post('includes/userunique.php', {
        uname: value
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Do stuff with the response
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Handle the error
    })
    .always(function() {
        // Do something regardless of whether successful or failure
    })
}
```